# How to set the key\value within the jQuery Autocomplete control with json data?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, autocomplete

How can I use this json data as data source of jquery autocomplete?

```
[{"uid":"123","UserName":"xxx"},{"uid":"124","UserName":"yyy"}]


<script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.core.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.position.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.widget.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.ui.autocomplete.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<input name="Txt1" type="text" id="Txt1">

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
$("#Txt1").autocomplete(
{
  source:[{"uid":"123","UserName":"xxx"},{"uid":"124","UserName":"yyy"}]
}
)
</script>
```

Comment: Does this JSON come from an ajax call?

Comment: yes it comes from an ajax call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the best practice with custom returned values is to create a parse function.  This allows you to do what you want with your returned JSON.  In this sample code, I do not address the ajax call, but I can add that as well if you need.  jQuery UI Autocomplete looks for a label and a value entity.  You can put either of those in as you see fit, or even do some custom stuff if needed.

```
var myStuff = [{
    "uid": "123",
    "UserName": "xxx"},
{
    "uid": "124",
    "UserName": "yyy"}];

function imAutocompleteJSONParse(data) {
    var rows = [];
    var rowData = null;
    var dataLength = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
        rowData = data[i];
        rows[i] = {
            label: rowData.UserName,
            value: rowData.UserName
        };
    }
    return rows;
}

$("#Txt1").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var rows = imAutocompleteJSONParse(myStuff);
        return response(rows);
    },
    minLength: 2
});
```

For clarity sake, I put this in a fiddle page so you can see it working: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/TRKeE/

NOW, as I suspect YOU want to do some custom/different stuff with the results, I have created this custom example on how to work with custom values: http://jsfiddle.net/MarkSchultheiss/TRKeE/2/

The difference is I changed the parse function and added a new autocomplete option.

```
var myStuff = [{
    "uid": "123",
    "UserName": "xxx"},
{
    "uid": "124",
    "UserName": "yyy"}];

function imAutocompleteJSONParse(data) {
    var rows = [];
    var rowData = null;
    var dataLength = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < dataLength; i++) {
        rowData = data[i];
        rows[i] = {
            uid: rowData.uid,
            UserName: rowData.UserName,
            label: rowData.UserName,
            value: rowData.uid
        };
    }
    return rows;
}

$("#Txt1").autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var rows = imAutocompleteJSONParse(myStuff);
        return response(rows);
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        var hasValue = (ui.item.value != undefined && ui.item.value != "" && ui.item.value != null);
        if (hasValue) {
            var focusedElement = $(this);
            focusedElement.val(ui.item.label);
            $('#labelResult').text(ui.item.label);
            $('#valueResult').text(ui.item.label);
            $('#customResult').text(ui.item.uid + ":" + ui.item.UserName);

            return false;
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }
    },
    minLength: 2
});
```

Comment: thank you very much. but when I type in the textBox it shows all of the items.it should show just the matched items.

Comment: Yes, this is due to the way I handle the result array. I filter my results prior to sending based on the text entered. You can use a .push() on the array if that is not your desire - for instance if you pre-load the array. In my case, I have tens of thousands of results and need the filter done server side.

Comment: Thanks for this - the combination between the select event and the key, value bits are really useful to me.

Answer (score -1):

really really simple

`$('#Txt1').autocomplete({source: 'URL to your JSON file / script'});`

and if you code is really really odd and you want to add json as a string use

`$('#Txt1').autocomplete({source: $.parseJSON(your_string) });`

Comment: what to do If I want to give the json as data source directly not a url?